# Probability of crossing hurdles in a race

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A competitor has to cross $n$ hurdles in some race. The probability to knock down any hurdle is $p$.

- What is the probability that the first knocked down hurdle is the $k^\text{th}$ ($1\le k \le n$)?
- What is the probability to knock down exactly $m$ hurdles ($1\le m \le n$)?
- What is the probability of knocking down $m$ consecutive hurdles?

Thanks for any help.

It's the third question that is confusing for me, I didn't understood it, my try gave me a probability exceeding 1 which I thought stupid to post as a try ( $(n-m+1)\times p^m$ ) When $n$ is big enough, this probability exceeds $1$.
If it wasn't for this confusion, it wouldn't have been worthy to be asked to be discussed. As for questions (1) and (2), the answers are quite immediate but they were posted so as to precise the context to the last question.

Comment: In the third question, is it exactly $m$ consecutive hurdles or at least $m$?  Either way, as JonMark says, it is rather harder.

Comment: Hint:  Knock down = p, not knock down = 1-p.1) First k-1 hurdles survive with prop. $(1-p)^{k-1}$, k th hurdle is knocked down with p. So? 2) prob of knocking down m hurdles, n-m are ok with prob ? But: multiply by the number of ways you can knock down m hurdles out of n.3) m consecutive: the probability of knocking down m, n-m surviving, you have in 2). Now: how many ways to knock down m consec. hurdles? Start counting: the very first m are knocked down, then1 st survives, 2, 3,.. are down, then, 2.  first survive..., count them and multiply. Helps?

Comment: Sure it helps thanks.
As for the third, I'm still analyzing JonMark Perry reply for the third question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part 1: To knock down any hurdle has probability $p$, therefore to not knock down a hurdle has probability $1-p$. The question asks for $k-1$ no-knock-down's, and then a knock-down, so the final probability is:

$$(1-p)^kp$$

Part 2: $n$ choose $m$ ways for this to happen, and the Binomial distribution formula gives the answer:

$$\binom{n}{m}p^m(1-p)^{n-m}$$

Part 3 is more difficult. If $m$ is not exact, the problem is very difficult. Assume exactly $m$ consecutive knock-downs - this has a probability $p^m(1-p)^2$. There are $n-m-2$ remaining hurdles, anything can happen to these. The $m+2$ run can start in any of $n-m-2$ places, and we also need to allow for the run happening first or last:

$$(n-m-2)p^m(1-p)^2\sum_{i=0}^{n-m-2} \binom{n-m-2}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-m-2-i}\\+
2p^m(1-p)\sum_{i=0}^{n-m-1} \binom{n-m-1}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-m-1-i}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had correct guesses for (1) and (2), for the third I thought $p^m$ was the answer but it's not.

Comment: Doesn't (3) disregard where in the sequence the consecutives occur?

Comment: Actually Dror, I think one should multiply by $n-m+1$ : the number of ways to choose the position of the first hurdle to be knocked down.

Comment: Thanks JonMark Perry, does your first answer work still for the case where $m$ is exact, right ?